# How to let Terminal on Mac OS behave show folders and executables and such in different colors?

Tags: terminal, color

On Linux (e.g. Ubuntu) the terminal shows you executables and folders and such in different colors so you can identify them easier. Is this possible on Mac OS Terminal, too?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add color output of the *ls* command, you need to edit your ~/.bash_profile and add:

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

This is just an example, look at the *ls* manpage on how to change specific color values.

Comment: where is the ~/.bash_profile??

Comment: The tilde ( ~ ) signifies your home folder. So it is in your home folder. It begins with a period, so it's a hidden file, so press Command + Shift + . to see hidden files.